# Can I validate an admin type user password at the same time that I logged in with another user type other than admin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, identity

Hopefully you can guide me to clarify whether it is possible with identity asp or what I should consult to solve the problem that I describe below:

The user laragutz is a user with a role of type "data register", his main task is to create new records. This type of user will have the option to be able to edit the records when he has made errors, as long as he has correctly provided the password of the administrator type user. Once the password is provided, it will allow him to go to the edit view. [Example index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGFQ.jpg)

Without closing the session of the user type "data register" so as not to relieve the responsibility of the user who was in charge of capturing and causing the error, since there is a table that keeps a history of movements, a type of event log.
Can I do that with Identity?? For example signinmanager??

With kind regards.

Comment: Try `UserManager.CheckPassword`

Comment: I will do it @VDWWD! Thank you for take the time to answer! –